# Collapsing the details row in a data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, master-detail

I have a data grid with a details row, something like:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Applications" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowStyle="{StaticResource CollapsedRow}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CanUserAddRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Applications}">

<DataGrid.Columns>
 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <Button Content='&#709;' FontSize="9" Name="ExpanderButton" Click="OnGroupChange" />
     </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTextColumn Width="181" Header="Application name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <!-- SOME DETAILS HERE -->
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Now the idea is that I have a data grid with additional columns with a button that will expand the details row, so my code behind is:

```
private void OnGroupChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollapseGroupDetails();
    for (var visible = (Visual)sender; visible != null; visible = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visible) as Visual)
    {
        if (visible.GetType() != typeof(DataGridRow))
            continue;

        var row = (DataGridRow)visible;
        var appName = (ExtenedApplicationFile)row.Item;
                ((ApplicationsViewModel)DataContext).SelectedApplicationFile = appName;

        row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    Applications.UpdateLayout();
}

private void CollapseGroupDetails()
{
    foreach (object item in Applications.ItemsSource)
    {
        if (!(Applications.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) is DataGridRow row) ||  row.DetailsVisibility != Visibility.Visible)
            continue;

        row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        break;
    }
}
```

So it works like: I click on a button, it expands the details row of the selected grid row and closes the others, but the problem is when I click on the button on an open row I want it to collapse, but

```
row.DetailsVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
```

Value of this property is already collapsed and it sets the property to visible again, but when I remove:

```
CollapseGroupDetails();
```

method it works, but if I click on the other row's button, the previously selected details row stays open. I have checked if I select a proper row but checking its index and it is correct. Is there a way to combine that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a temporary copy of the `Visibility` value before you set the property:

```
private void OnGroupChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = null;
    for (var visible = (Visual)sender; visible != null; visible = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visible) as Visual)
    {
        if (visible.GetType() != typeof(DataGridRow))
            continue;

        row = (DataGridRow)visible;
        var appName = (ExtenedApplicationFile)row.Item;
        ((ApplicationsViewModel)DataContext).SelectedApplicationFile = appName;

        break;
    }

    if (row != null)
    {
        Visibility currentVisibility = row.DetailsVisibility;
        CollapseGroupDetails();
        row.DetailsVisibility = currentVisibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        CollapseGroupDetails();
    }

    Applications.UpdateLayout();
}
```